# Can we reliably log the result of every gRPC call to our grpc-java server?

Tags: java, grpc, grpc-java

We have a custom `ServerInterceptor` for logging every call our grpc-java server receives. It wraps the `ServerCall` passed on to `next::startCall` with a `SimpleForwardingServerCall` that overrides `close(Status,Metadata)` for logging the status of the call and tracking total time elapsed between `interceptCall` and `close`. We expected this to result in logging status and tracking elapsed time for every call received.

We've found one case where our interceptor logged in the body of `interceptCall`, and then an inner interceptor did some logging in its `interceptCall`, but we never saw any more logging for the request. Other context suggests that there were connection issues between the client and server at the time.

Can we expect `ServerCall::close(Status,Metadata)` be called for every RPC call, regardless of client or connection misbehavior? If not, is there some other callback that we may have missed that would indicate that a call has "died?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `ServerCall.Listener.onComplete()` and `ServerCall.Listener.onCancel()`. `onComplete()` is called after `ServerCall.close()` is processed successfully. `onCancel()` is used for any communication error or cancellation. Note that it is possible to receive `onCancel()` after the application calls `ServerCall.close()`.